# How can you force Fluid Image processing?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have noticed that TYPO3 is not processing images unless they need resizing.
This means I'm getting unoptimised jpg files slowing down page speed.

Is there a way to tell it to process the image regardless of dimensions?

`<f:media file="{file}" maxWidth="{dimensions.width}" />`

If there is no proper way to do this, is there perhaps a filter I could apply at such a small level that it would not visually change anything but would force it to create a processed file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a solution to optimize the original files.

- Once, if they are only images of your sitepackage/theme
- Periodically via cronjob, if the images are uploaded by editors

Have a look to [jpegoptim](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim) which can be used for bulk optimizing:

```
find . -iname "*.jp*g" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 jpegoptim -o --strip-all --max=90
```

Comment: For editor uploaded images. I would be worried periodically doing it would allow quality loss to accumulate after optimising multiple times.

Comment: And your editors are scaling images to the needed dimension before uploading???  Wow... Haven't tried it with source folders yet but only with the `__processed__` folders.
Maybe, it would also be a solution delivering webp format (https://www.dpool.com/blog/index.php/2020/07/10/typo3-in-15-minuten-webp-faehig-machen/) or building an own "helper" like plan2net/webp.

Comment: Happens all the time, mostly with `maxWidth`. Anything below max width is not processed, doesn't need to be exact. Webp is an interesting idea, though plan2net/webp only does images that are being processed, so it has the same problem.

Comment: That's why I wrote "building an own 'helper' **like** plan2net/webp" ;) I didn't think, there is already a working solution for your requirement.